# How to open pdf in another application using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

How can I open a pdf file in Adobe Acrobat Reader using swift (or iBook)?

I have the path of the pdf file in my application: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/86AFFF55-694F-4D74-96BF-8F36C79E303F/Documents/file.pdf`

What I am currently doing is:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "com.adobe.Adobe-Reader://"+path)
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

This opens the Adobe Acrobat Reader program, but does not load the pdf file.

Comment: http://mariobuonomo.blogspot.be/2015/08/swift-ios-8-open-remote-file-pdf-with.html something like here ?

Comment: Maybe make a webview first and watch if your pdf actually gets loaded in your app

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959023/swift-how-to-open-local-pdf-from-my-app-to-ibooks