# Load PDF in uiwebview and save to iBooks

Tags: swift, uiwebview, iosdeployment

I am creating an simple app which load pdf file from a particular website into `UIWEBVIEW` and i want to save it into `iBook`. I was finding many tutorial but doesn't make sense.I want to know how i am able to save pdf file which i have loaded in `UIWEBVIEW` and save it to `iBook`. Thank you.

```
let urlPDF = NSURL(string: "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_tutorial.pdf")
```

Here is code that i loaded it to `uiwebview`.

```
let request = NSURLRequest(url: urlPDF! as URL)
webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

Comment: First you need to save your file from the web and then you can use this answer to work with iBook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959023/swift-how-to-open-local-pdf-from-my-app-to-ibooks/29831628

Comment: @VictorSigler thank you sir. it works fine now.